# How to move the last column "option" to the first column

Tags: phpmyadmin

How could I move to first column my last option column ?
I have servals columns, and I have to scroll a loooooong time to get those options.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toothed wheel configuration button is located on the top right of the screen and permit to configure this.

Answer (score 1):

This is controlled by this directive:
https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_RowActionLinks

So yours must be set to 'right' and you should try 'left'. Also, it can be set per-user so visit Parameters from the main page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, btw I've just found a little grey toothed wheel on the top right banner of phpmyadmin where I can select the placement of the action column...